# python code not understand. Step by Step explanation of this code

Tags: python, swap

```
a,b=1,2
a,b=b,a=a,b
print(a,b)
# 2 1
```

If someone could give me a line by line explanation of this code, help me plz

Comment: what is unclear about it?

Comment: i don't understan line2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought the swap would happen like `a,b=b,a`. but, no swap occurs on line 2. Converting line 2 is as follows.

```
a, b = b, a = a, b
```

1. a,b --> (1,2)
2. a,b=(1,2)
3. b,a=(1,2)

It's just like assigning a value to a variable.

It is equal to a=b=c=1.

```
a=1, b=1, c=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure! So, line 1:

```
a,b = 1,2
```

This basically creates two variables, a and b, and assigns them values on the other side of the equal sign from left to right. So, a = 1, and b = 2.

Line 2 basically swaps everything around. As I see it, each quantity (e.g. a,b or b,a) is being made equal to something else. For example if a,b = 1,2 and you say a,b = b,a you're basically saying a,b = 2,1 so a becomes 2, and b becomes 1. When you print it, that's what you get.

Comment: but it uses `a, b = b, a = a, b` not `a, b = b, a`, so why doesn't the last bit affect it and why does it not cause an error?

Comment: Because by the time it does that last one, a already equals 2 and b already equals 1, so putting a, b makes it 2, 1.

Comment: ok that makes sense

Comment: Ummm... changing the second line to `b,a=b,a=a,b` has the same result.

Comment: That's because it's originally assigned as a,b = 1,2. It might help to think of them as separate variables, because that's what they are. a = 1, b = 2. It's just the order in the commas.

Comment: I understand. Swap happens only once.
But one question is, isn't the operation assignment starting from the back?
In `a,b=b,a=a,b`, is `a,b=b,a` executed first?

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know that's what's happening.